# Как разбить число по разрядам

Tags: xcode, swift

Есть число 1234567
Как разбить запятыми число по разрядам, чтобы получилось 1,234,567?
Код должен быть универсальным: при вводе 12345678 должно получится 12,345,678 и т.д.

Comment: @Bezarius Спасибо!

Comment: если мой ответ вам помог, то нажмите галочку,  напротив моего поста, что бы было ясно, что вам больше не нужна помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно применить форматирование подобно примеру ниже:

```
    var price = 123.436

    var formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle
    // formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale() // This is the default
    formatter.stringFromNumber(price) // "$123.44"

    formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "es_CL")
    formatter.stringFromNumber(price) // $123"

    formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "es_ES")
    formatter.stringFromNumber(price) // "123,44 €"
```

Если вы работаете не с валютой(как я предположил), то вам нужно воспользоваться Decimal Style

Comment: судя по тому, что в примере '12,345,678' это явно не валюта